# Regression to fill NA values

Tags: neural-network, keras, regression

As a part of an exercise, I have the [following dataset](https://data.heatonresearch.com/data/t81-558/crx.csv). Note that I have no idea where the values come from (are they based on something real or are they random numbers? Don't know...)

```
    a1     a2      s3 a4 a5  a6  a7    a8 a9 a10  a11 a12 a13    a14  a15 a16
0    b  30.83   0.000  u  g   w   v  1.25  t   t    1   f   g  202.0    0   +
1    a  58.67   4.460  u  g   q   h  3.04  t   t    6   f   g   43.0  560   +
2    a  24.50   0.500  u  g   q   h  1.50  t   f    0   f   g  280.0  824   +
3    b  27.83   1.540  u  g   w   v  3.75  t   t    5   t   g  100.0    3   +
4    b  20.17   5.625  u  g   w   v  1.71  t   f    0   f   s  120.0    0   +
..  ..    ...     ... .. ..  ..  ..   ... ..  ..  ...  ..  ..    ...  ...  ..
685  b  21.08  10.085  y  p   e   h  1.25  f   f    0   f   g  260.0    0   -
686  a  22.67   0.750  u  g   c   v  2.00  f   t    2   t   g  200.0  394   -
687  a  25.25  13.500  y  p  ff  ff  2.00  f   t    1   t   g  200.0    1   -
688  b  17.92   0.205  u  g  aa   v  0.04  f   f    0   f   g  280.0  750   -
689  b  35.00   3.375  u  g   c   h  8.29  f   f    0   t   g    0.0    0   -

[690 rows x 16 columns]
```

I have to fill the NA values of columns `a2` and `a14` using regression, in which a neural network is trained on the the following columns: `['s3','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a15']`. The idea is that a regression should provide better estimates than filling with the median value.

These are the steps that I followed:

- converted to one hot encoding the categorical columns `'a9','a10','a11','a12'`.
- normalization of the numerical columns `'s3','a8','a11','a15'` with `scipy.stats.zscore`
- for `a2`, extracted the rows in which `a2` is not NA. Created a train/validation set. Created a neural network, trained it and predict over the validation set.
- same for `a14`.

The problem is that my predictions are very poor: I've played with architecture (number of layers and neurons), [loss functions](https://keras.io/api/losses/regression_losses/), [optimizers](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/), batch size... Nothing seems to bring me close to a good estimate.

Since I'm new to machine learning, I probably did something wrong, but I need help in figuring out what. Here is the code and my results.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import zscore
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics

def chart(history, pred, y, sort=True, title=None):
    # plot loss and prediction
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    ax[0].plot(history.history['loss'], label="train")
    ax[0].plot(history.history['val_loss'], label="val")
    ax[0].set_xlabel("epochs")
    ax[0].set_ylabel("loss")
    ax[0].legend()
    
    t = pd.DataFrame({'pred': pred, 'y': y.flatten()})
    if sort:
        t.sort_values(by=['y'], inplace=True)
    ax[1].plot(t['y'].tolist(), label='expected')
    ax[1].plot(t['pred'].tolist(), label='prediction')
    ax[1].set_ylabel('output')
    ax[1].legend()
    if title:
        fig.suptitle(title)
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

df = pd.read_csv("https://data.heatonresearch.com/data/t81-558/crx.csv",na_values=['?'])
df_original = df.copy()

# one hot encoding
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['a9'],prefix="a9")],axis=1)
df.drop('a9', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['a10'],prefix="a10")],axis=1)
df.drop('a10', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['a12'],prefix="a12")],axis=1)
df.drop('a12', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['a13'],prefix="a13")],axis=1)
df.drop('a13', axis=1, inplace=True)

# normalization
df['s3'] = zscore(df['s3'])
df['a8'] = zscore(df['a8'])
df['a11'] = zscore(df['a11'])
df['a15'] = zscore(df['a15'])

# drop uneccessary columns
check = lambda t: any(s in t for s in ['s3','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a15'])
df.drop([t for t in df.columns if not check(t)], axis=1, inplace=True)

def apply_regression(column):
    # select all rows where column is not NA
    idx = df_original[column].isna()
    x = df[~idx].values
    y = df_original[column][~idx].values

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(    
        x, y, test_size=0.2,
        random_state=42
    )

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=x.shape[1], activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

    history = model.fit(
        x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        verbose=0, epochs=1000, batch_size=16
    )

    # Plot the chart
    pred = model.predict(x_test)
    mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(pred, y_test)
    chart(history, pred.flatten(), y_test, title="MSE column {}: {}".format(column, mse))

apply_regression("a2")
apply_regression("a14")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your features are continuous or have a relationship of precedence, you can fill the NaN values by the column before it, then the column after it.
It can be implemented using `ffill` and `bfill` functions in pandas, here's how to use it: https://navinniish001.medium.com/pandas-bfill-and-ffill-b79e46ab87ae